# printing python results to a txt file

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to print the results of my program to a file named by the user.
My program creates the file but it does not write to the file. My code is working how I want, just having problem with the printing. I need the random file string to print to a file named by the user of the interface.

```
from random import randrange
from random import choice


def randomShape():
    x = randrange (0,400)
    y = randrange (0,400)
    x2 = randrange(0,400)
    y2 = randrange(0,400)

    radius = randrange (0,100)
    red = randrange (192, 208)
    blue = randrange(100,140)
    green = randrange(150,175)
    shape = ['cirle;','rectangle;']
    randomShape = choice (shape)

    if randomShape == 'cirle;':
        print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",radius,";",red,",",blue,",",green)

    elif randomShape != 'cirle;':
        print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",x2,",",y2,";",red,",",blue,",",green)


def getColor( colorString ):
    tokens = colorString.split(',')
    if len( tokens ) == 3:
        return color_rgb( int( tokens[0] ), int(tokens[1]), int( tokens[2] ))
    elif len( colorString ) > 0:
       return colorString.strip()
    else:
        return 'white'



def main():
    kFile = input("Enter the drawing file name to create:")
    openfile = open(kFile,"w")

    q = int(input("Enter the number of shapes to make:"))

    for x in range(q):
        print (randomShape(),kFile)



main()
```

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint absent what you're trying and what errors you're getting.  

Does the program print to the screen successfully?  Also, you should add a file close condition (eg, `kFile.close()`) after you're done with it.

Comment: I need to print the results of randomShape() to the file that is created when the user inputs the name @  "Enter the drawing file name to create:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from random import randrange
from random import choice
from graphics import color_rgb

def randomShape():
    x = randrange (0,400)
    y = randrange (0,400)
    x2 = randrange(0,400)
    y2 = randrange(0,400)

    radius = randrange (0,100)
    red = randrange (192, 208)
    blue = randrange(100,140)
    green = randrange(150,175)
    shape = ['cirle;','rectangle;']
    randomShape = choice(shape)

    if randomShape == 'cirle;':
        print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",radius,";",red,",",blue,",",green)

    elif randomShape != 'cirle;':
        print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",x2,",",y2,";",red,",",blue,",",green)
    return randomShape


def getColor( colorString ):
    tokens = colorString.split(',')
    if len( tokens ) == 3:
        return color_rgb( int( tokens[0] ), int(tokens[1]), int( tokens[2] ))
    elif len( colorString ) > 0:
       return colorString.strip()
    else:
        return 'white'

def main():
    kFile = input("Enter the drawing file name to create:")
    q = int(input("Enter the number of shapes to make:"))

    with open(kFile, "w") as file:
        for x in range(q):
            file.write(randomShape())

main()
```

In the above code, you have to return `randomShape` value from the `randomShape()` and write the output to the file. And, one more thing to note here is you should consider using append mode like `open(kFile, "a")`, to keep appending to the existing file and not overwrite it every time you run the function.

Comment: the program wont accept the function. I get an File "/Users/user/Downloads/join.py", line 43, in main
    file.write(randomShape())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: replace file.write(randomShape()) with file.write(str(randomShape()))

Comment: See this output:                                                                                               Enter the drawing file name to create:abcde.txt
Enter the number of shapes to make:3
cirle; 249 , 61 ; 15 ; 200 , 138 , 168
cirle; 360 , 333 ; 18 ; 202 , 128 , 152
rectangle; 397 , 130 ; 140 , 7 ; 207 , 116 , 160

Comment: Okay, now I got it. You are getting None because you are not returning anything from randomShape(). As a result, None is going into the file.open() method. Try returning randomShape value from randomShape(), what I am doing. That's why I am not getting any error. check out my code. And, don't forget to use append mode if you want to append to the same file multiple times.

Comment: My code is coming out as a straight line. is your coming out like that as well? I would like each string RandomShape in its own row in the file. sorry if I'm sound like an idiot but I very new to coding

Comment: Yeah. For each string to on a separate line, replace file.write(randomShape()) with file.write(randomShape()+"\n"). If this solves your problem, please don't forget to accept my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
print (randomShape(),kFile)
```

This is not going to write to the file.
After you open the file with:

```
openfile = open(kFile,"w")
```

You now have a file handle in openFile. You can use the methods on this to write the data out (and make sure you close the file too). Generally speaking you can use the write method - https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write

So in your case you'd want to use something like 
`kFile.write(randomShape())`

Also as a sidenote, your `randomShape()` function doesnt return any data as well to the function call. So you will probably need to modify that to use `return` instead of `print` in:

`print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",radius,";",red,",",blue,",",green)` and `print(randomShape,x,",",y,";",x2,",",y2,";",red,",",blue,",",green)`

Comment: when i changed it to return it prints out all the commas and things in dont need. i need to to print out like this: Rectangle; 127, 143; 318, 332; 32, 208, 253

Answer (score 0):

In general recommended approach is to use `with` statement. As Mark Meyer pointed out, you also need to write to file object, not to string with its name.

Combining both information, try with sth like:

```py
filename = input("Filename: ")
with open(filename, "w") as openedFile:
    print("Some data", file=openedFile)
```

Comment: ok its printing out the shape but its not print out the values (integers) for each shape